# Populate array in a for loop

Tags: arrays, bash

I have an array of strings to pass through a script. The script is well-behaved, and will return error code 0 if the string "passes" and non-zero if it "fails." If the string passes, it should be included in a final array to be output or written to file or etc.

The problem I'm having is that the only item ending up in my final array is the first "passing" string.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# validator.sh

if [[ $1 -le 10 ]]; then
    exit 0
else
    exit 1
fi
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# main.sh

numbers=(2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16)
keep=()
for n in ${numbers[@]}; do
    if ./validator.sh $n; then
        keep+=("$n")
    fi
done
echo $keep
```

Running main.sh produces:

```
$ ./main.sh
2
```

but I expect `2 4 6 8 10`

Comment: And if you quote `${numbers[@]}` like `"${numbers[@]}"` and `$n` to `"$n"`, does it help?, also `echo "${keep[@]}"` and not `"$keep"` since `$keep` is just the first element `${keep[0]}`

Comment: Have you run your scripts through shellcheck?

Comment: `$keep` is just the first element in the array. To reference all elements use `${keep[@]}`

Comment: Ah there's the stupid mistake. Using `${keep[@]}` instead of `$keep` fixed it. If either of you would like to post that as an answer I'd love to accept it. Otherwise I will self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you meant `keep` to be an array of matching elements, change:

```
keep+=("$n")
```

to

```sh
keep="$keep $n"
```

That would work with any Bourne compatible shell and is therefore better, if you're looking for BASH specific solution, the below will also work:

```sh
keep+="${n} "
```

If you DO want it to be an array, then in order to output all elements, you can use:

```
echo ${keep[@]}
```

As noted by @Jetchisel and @kamilCuk in the comments.
Since you wrote you want to output all elements or save them to a file, I had assumed you don't actually need an array here but perhaps you plan to use this data in other ways later:)